# Image wont go to left side underneath a floated paragraph

Tags: html, css

Okay so this is the CSS and basically I have two paragraphs and I just want to put a picture below the paragraph on the left.  It is a longer paragraph than the one on the right so I think that's what's effecting it.  The picture always ends up on the right side below the right paragraph.  Can someone please help?

```
body{
        font-family: sans-serif;
        margin:auto;
    }

    .p1 {
        width: 425px;
        float:left;
        padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius:5px;
        height:auto;
    }

    #dates img{
        float: left;
    }

    .p2 {
        width:405px;
        float:right;
        padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .content    {
        width:850px;
        text-align:center;
        margin:auto;
    }

    h1  {
        text-align:center;
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }

    h3  {
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:0px;
    }
```

Comment: Okay working on that jsfiddle right now sorry new guy here.

Comment: Got it! http://jsfiddle.net/saQataQ/LpKhp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `clear: both;` to the `#dates img` style.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bQXH/2/).

Comment: Glad to help.  I updated the link to a fiddle that is a fork of yours.  If you found this helpful, let others know by accepting it.